# RPi3 bitcoind and solo mining

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am setting up a Raspberry Pi 3 to be a full node and miner. I know I will probably never win a mining block. I am doing this for fun and learning.

I do not want to do a pool. I want to just do solo mining to learn how it works.

I set up bitcoind from the official bitcoin 0.13.2 git repo.

I found a cpuminer (minerd) and am setting that up.

The question I have is about the wallet address that will receive any bitcoins that get generated as a reward for mining a block.

I know that when a miner wins the mining of a block it creates a transaction in the block to receive the bit coins that are rewarded.

What I don't understand is how that wallet address gets created.

I have created my own wallet on another computer and would just like any rewarded coins for mining to go into that wallet.

I also know that you can create a wallet on the mining computer (RPi) itself. Is that required?

Please give some instructions on how to set up that mining reward address wherever it needs to be set up.

Like I said I probably will never be lucky enough to mind a block, but if I happen to get lucky I want to have a proper address set up to receive that reward.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/master/cpu-miner.c#L188) cpuminer has a `--coinbase-addr` parameter which accepts a bitcoin address (for example: `./cpuminer --coinbase-addr=1abcdef...`, I believe you only need to set this.

The program [checks if you have provided an address](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/46e919f93cb16756a92fe8c957e78ed1fc634384/cpu-miner.c#L450) and if not then switches to "getwork" mode, unless you disabled it by adding the `--no-gbt` command line switch.